# Can't backup anymore Facebook & WhatsApp with adb

Tags: backup, facebook, whatsapp-messenger

I've always backed up my Facebook & WhatsApp data on Android with the following command:

```
adb backup -noapk com.facebook.katana
```

and

```
adb backup -noapk com.whatsapp
```

Now, it seem it can't backup it when I run it. The backup procedure starts, but no good backup.ab file is created.

Does someone noticed this ?

Maybe they changed in the Android manifest:

```
<application>
    ...
    android:allowBackup="true"
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: After some experiments, I also reproduced this "issue". The backup for both app returns same content (which I assume is empty, but haven't checked that). Seems they protect their data now...